# Buying Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to buy Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition in order to remotely install it on the server.

The question is: Can I buy a licence in USA and pay in US dollars? OR do I have to buy it in my country (Portugal)? Since the servers are in Germany, should I buy the licence in Germany?

(And if anyone know a good reseller I would apreciate)

Answer (score 1):

If you buy through [Microsoft Select](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/select.aspx) or [Enterprise Agreement](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/enterprise.aspx) in the US you can allocate them overseas.

Answer (score 0):

Why buy? Rent it using SPLA ;) Cheaper, once you count in the fact that you get the updates for free.